# Solaris/OpenSolaris resources

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

What are some good Solaris/OpenSolaris resources?

Please list them whether they are online/offline or free/for payment.

Answer (score 2):

[Ben Rockwood's blog](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/) - online & free

[Sun BigAdmin](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/home/index.jsp) - online & free, but may link to non-free Sun stuff

Comment: Some of the non-free Sun stuff is free, you just need a SunSolve account.  The stuff that isn't free requires a Sun support contract of one sort or another (hardware contract access is different than Solaris OS support contract).

Answer (score 2):

[Blog O’ Matty](http://prefetch.net/blog/)

More than Solaris but I've found some real gems on his blog (like Oracle Sun cluster information).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [LKSF book here](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/).

The best way to learn is to dive in to it. Install OpenSolaris on a Vm and work away.

Answer (score 0):

Although Solaris is dying somewhat in the hacker space, SunOS/Solaris used to be king of the hill in the unix hacker community.  There is still a core of Solaris people on usenet and quite a body of online literature.  Solaris is also a fairly mature, stable platform so much of the archived historical material is still relevant in a way that 10-year old docs on Linux might not be.

Answer (score 0):

- [Getting started with OpenSolaris 2009.06](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2009.06/getstart/) (free) provides an introduction to the OpenSolarisTM operating system, as well as instructions for installing and configuring the OpenSolaris release;
- [OpenSolaris Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470385480) (Amazon), [sample chapters](https://blogs.oracle.com/dminer/entry/opensolaris_bible_sample_chapters).

Answer (score 0):

The Sun Freeware site: http://www.sunfreeware.com/ is indispensable and free.

Answer (score 0):

The opensolaris forums are a logical place to start if you have specific issues:

http://opensolaris.org/jive/index.jspa?categoryID=1

I often find useful stuff on [blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com), but it's not exclusively opensolaris of course. 

The community documentation feels a bit dated in many places, but is still extremely useful. 

http://opensolaris.org/os/community/documentation/