# List of freely available system administrator books

Tags: untagged

On the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books, I'm trying to create a wiki of system administrator books with open source licenses, like Creative Commons, GPL, etc. Feel free to pour in your recommendations.

**Linux**

- [Linux Network Administrator's Guide, 2nd Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linag2/book/index.html)

**Bash**

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

**MySQL**

- [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

**Apache**

- [Apache Dektop Reference](http://www.apacheref.com/download.html)

**Networking**

- [TCP/IP Tutorial and Technical Overview](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/gg243376.html?Open)

Answer (score 3):

I use Python for system administration, this book is under GNU Free Documentation License:
[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.org/)

This one is about the Linux Kernel: [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) and published under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 license

O'Reilly has also published a number of [Open Books](http://oreilly.com/openbook/). [Learning Debian](http://oreilly.com/catalog/debian/chapter/book/index.html), [Version Control with subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), [Using Samba](http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/index.html) are quite outdated but still interesting.

Answer (score 1):

- [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/)
- [Mac OS X Server Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/MacOSXServer/)
- [Bind 9.6 Administrator's Reference Manual](https://www.isc.org/files/Bv9.6ARM.pdf)
- [DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/)
- [Reference documentation for all Juniper Networks products](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/)
- [Cisco's reference guides](http://www.cisco.com/cisco/web/psa/reference.html)
- [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) (not a book, but a great reference for admins who operates on many kind of unix systems)

Answer (score 0):

See also [OpenSolaris/Solaris resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/32190/solaris-opensolaris-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Perl Training Australia have an excellent set of course notes for learning perl at http://perltraining.com.au/notes.html.  These are the notes they use in their courses, but they're available for free download and use.

Course books available are:

- Programming Perl
- Object Oriented Perl
- Perl Security
- Database Programming with Perl
- Web Development with Perl
- Perl for System Administration

Highly Recommended for anyone wanting to learn perl.